# How to execute method before scoped service is disposed in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a custom middleware whose purpose is to subscribe to EF Core dbcontext events and track the changes that happen to the entities. 
The middleware instantiates my InteractionService as a scoped instance at the beginning of each request. This is how my middleware looks like:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseDbContextActivityTracker<TContext>(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var service = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<InteractionService<TContext>>();
        await next.Invoke();
        service.PersistLogs();
    });

    return app;
}
```

and this is how I use the middleware in my Confiure method of the Startup class:

```
options.UseDbContextActivityTracker<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

In the constructor of my InteractionService I get a reference to the dbcontext through the DI and I subscribe to the events:

```
public InteractionService(TContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.context.ChangeTracker.StateChanged += ChangeTracker_StateChanged;
}
```

While listening to the events that happen to the dbContext during the duration of a request I am storing relevant information into my own entities and it works great. However, at the end of the request, I want to save changes to the database. I tried making my InteractionService class IDisposable and in the Dispose method, I am invoking another DbContext in which I save my entities. As expected I got the error "Connection already closed". 
**What is the right place to save my entities to the db after the request has been finished?**

Comment: You probably don't need that at all, EF Core uses .NET Core logging. Check [EF Core Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://wildermuth.com/2018/11/07/EntityFrameworkCore-Logging-in-ASP-NET-Core). In any case EF Core change tracking is an *EF Core* concern, not an ASP.NET Core concern. The proper way to configure this would be during EF Core configuration

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The reason I am doing this is because I need to be able to show the supervisor users of my app the activity that has been going on by the supervised users.

Comment: Check Julie Lehrman's [Logging SQL and Change-Tracking Events in EF Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt830355) to see what's available. You'll see that `ChangeTracking` is already available as a category

Comment: It has some good points but in any case I still need to do it my way. I need a way to access the database and save data into it before the request is finished but right after the mvc middleware has completed executing so there are no new changes and my tracker can safely persist the logs that it caught.

Comment: In that case the question isn't `What is the right place to save my entities to the db after the request has been finished?` but how to get a properly scoped DbContext to write the changes. Where's the code that *saves* those changes? It probably needs to create its own scoped DbContext

Comment: You are right. Right now the code that saves those changes is located inside a method on the scoped `InteractionService` class. The method is called `PersistLogs()` and inside the method I call `mydbcontext.SaveChanges()`. I call this method in my middleware right after the `next()` call so it is invoked after all other middlewares have finished their job. But at that point looks like `mydbcontext` is already being destroyed. So, are you suggesting that I should manually create new instance of `mydbcontext` inside the PersistLogs() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Panagiotis Kanavos pointed me to the right direction. My problem was how to get a properly scoped DbContext to write the changes. In my `InteractionService` instead of injecting the DbContext through the constructor I created it manually by using the serviceProvider. I changed this:

```
public CampusAxessInteractionStore(MyDbContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

to this:

```
public CampusAxessInteractionStore(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var scopeResolver = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
    this.context = scopeResolver.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CampusAxessDbContext>();
}
```

and now the saving works. **I am still not sure if this is the right approach though**. If someone can point me to how this should be properly done please do and I will remove my answer and mark your answer as the correct.